# How to use Auth0 Hook to call an API endpoint after a user signs up?

Tags: javascript, auth0

I'm trying to inject new user into a separate database after they sign up on Auth0. I was told that using hook is sufficient but I'm not sure how to make the call.

I tried

```
  var django_endpoint = 'some/endpoint/';
  var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            alert(this.responseText);
        }
    };
  xhttp.open("POST", django_endpoint, true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhttp.send('{"username": user.email}');
  cb(null, user, context);
```

and ran it, but my endpoint is not receiving anything although the result shows 200 on the auth0 test screen